# Are there Ubuntu Bluetooth Low Energy drivers for Macs running Ubuntu?

Tags: bluetooth

Are there any Bluetooth Low Energy Linux drivers that can be installed on a Mac running Ubuntu? My Mac reports BCM_4364B0 as its Bluetooth chip which I assume to be a Broadcom chip.

Comment: I don't think so, but you'll need to ask Brodecom to make sure.

Comment: There are no "bluetooth drivers" for Linux. BT devices are supported by Linux kernel. You need to find out what features are supported.